# mkdir() not actually creating the directory

Tags: php

Basically when I click my submit button the code should create a random string that is 5 characters in length. Then it should make a folder (relative position) with the name being the random string generated. Then it should create an index file and write the "content" variable to the file. Unfortunately it never even makes the directory. Any help? I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
    <?php
            $characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; // Valid Folder Characters
            if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                $folder = randomString($characters, 5);
                $file = fopen($folder . "/index.html", "w");
                $content = "File Content";
                mkdir($folder, 0777);
                fwrite($file, $content);
                fclose($file);
            }
            // Generate Random Folder Name
            function randomString($valid_chars, $length) {
                $random_string = "";
                $num_valid_chars = strlen($valid_chars);
                for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                    $random_pick = mt_rand(1, $num_valid_chars);
                    $random_char = $valid_chars[$random_pick - 1];
                    $random_string .= $random_char;
                }
                return $random_string;
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: are you able to create file?

Comment: Does the web server have write permission in the directory in which you're working? i.e. the directory where your code is placed. You probably need to set `g+w` on that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have writable permission where or in which directory you are creating new directory and for check try

```
if (!mkdir($folder, 0777, true)) {
    die('Failed to create folders...');
}
```

Also you need to first create dir then file open

```
 if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
     $folder = randomString($characters, 5);
     if (!mkdir($folder, 0777, true)) {
       die('Failed to create folders...');
     }
     $file = fopen($folder . "/index.html", "w");
     $content = "File Content";
     fwrite($file, $content);
     fclose($file);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
$oldmask = umask(0);
if(!file_exists($dir)) mkdir($dir, 0777);
umask($oldmask);
```